# Pine script intellisense ( autocomplete ) without Ctrl + Space

Tags: editor, pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I have been using the pinescript editor in tradingview.com

I could not able to configure the editor much, Not even font size.
I am executing scripts in order to make changes in the editor like below.

```js
$('#editor').css('font-size','21px');
```

I want the editor to suggest me without entering Ctrl + Space.
And also is there a generic advice as a newbie for using pine-script and editor. Some hack or tools which I can use ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use VS Code, have a look at the first line [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/resources/#text-editor-highlighters-and-utilities-for-pine). It's an add-on by RicardoSantos.

*Disclosure: the link in this answer points to a PineCoders FAQ entry. I am a member of the PineCoders community and I most probably wrote that FAQ entry. PineCoders is a TradingView-supported group of volunteer Pine coders and PineCoders' website is strictly educational. Neither TradingView nor PineCoders benefits financially from sending traffic to pinecoders.com, and the site contains no affiliate/referral links.*

Comment: Thanks, The `vscode_pinescript_snippet` is very helpful. Just tried it.